# JqGrid pgtext issue

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid

pgtext is not displaying properly in the pager. What could be the reason?

[image]

Grid Options

```js
pager: pagerID,
gridview: true,
navOptions: {
    position: "left",
    addtext: "Add",
    edittext: "Edit",
    deltext: "Delete",
    iconsOverText: true
},
loadonce: false,
pagerpos: 'center',
rowNum: pagesize,
viewrecords: true,
```

Pager Setting

```js
$("#"+childGridID).navGrid(pagerID,
   // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
   { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false,
    refresh: false, view: false, cloneToTop: false },
   // options for the Edit Dialog
   {...........................
```

Comment: You added many tags about different products, which are based on jqGrid. Which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Could you provide the demo (in jsfiddle, for example), which reproduces the problem?

Comment: I am using free jqGrid. I figured out the issue. One of the parent CSS property overlying the jqgrid css property. Fixed the parent css.